# Visual Studio comment position adjusting

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Okay, maybe it's a bit noob and silly question but I couldn't google anything

When I'm writing my code in C#, I'm making comments at the end of the command lines

Some lines are longer and some are shorter so the comments are at different positions too

For example:

```
int N=10; //comment1
SomeFunctionWithLongName() //comment2
AnotherFunction() //comment3
```

And I'd like to have it in cleaner and neater form:

```
int N=10;                     //comment1
SomeFunctionWithLongName()    //comment2
AnotherFunction()             //comment3
```

I can work hard and use tabs and spaces to get the result but it's tedious and gets all destroyed if I change anything in my code

Is there any automatic tool that would set the equal positions for all my comments, adjusted for the longest line

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, it's better to put comments above the line that needs commenting. You may want to read up on the C# guidelines [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff926074.aspx) it has a good guide for comments, too.

Answer (score 2):

*Well*, unfortunately there is no *directly* option in Visual Studio 2010 for aligment comments like your situation.

But in my mind, I have an idea. There is an extension called [`Code alignment`](http://www.codealignment.com/) for Visual Studio 2010 and 2012. Let me show you a piece of code with this extenion;

When you write;

```
foo = bar();
foobar = foo();
```

The extension aligns this lines based on `=` ;

```
foo    = bar;
foobar = foo;
```

So when you write your comments, they are automaticly will align like;

```
foo    = bar; //comment1
foobar = foo; //comment2
```